# how can i fix including path error in visual code

Tags: c, ubuntu

hello while compiling a c code i got this error concerning the library

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

all the include are not recognized .
Despite i have including

> "/usr/include"

in

> "the icludingPath"

in the

> "c_cpp_properties.json"

But i still have the same problem . i'm working with visual code
This the configuration :

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include" 
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/cpp",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: The error you quote is not related to an include problem. Please show a [mre], especially showing how you define the function `main()`.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 printf("Hello world!");
 return 0;
}

Comment: this is a the example just for testing i guess the error is from the configuration  @Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the "/usr/include" in the Including Path It is necessary to do a restart for the visual code . Now it's works .